# VisualVM cannot connect to any port except for 1099

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jvm, visualvm

I have a remote jvm application running inside docker container managed by kubernetes:

```
java -jar /path/to/app.jar
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote  
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1099
  -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
```

When I try to debug using port forwarding and VisualVM, it works only when I use port 1099 on local machine. Ports 1098, 10900, or any other don't work. This one works for VisualVM: `kubectl port-forward <pod-name> 1099:1099`. **This one doesn't:** `kubectl port-forward <pod-name> 1098:1099`

I use "Add JMX Connection" option in VisualVM, connecting to `localhost:1099` or `localhost:1098`. The former works, the latter doesn't.

Why can't I use non-1099 ports with VisualVM?

**UPD**
I believe the issue is related to VisualVM, because port forwarding seems to work fine whatever local port I choose:

```
$ kubectl port-forward <pod> 1098:1099
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:1098 -> 1099
Forwarding from [::1]:1098 -> 1099
Handling connection for 1098
Handling connection for 1098
```

Comment: Can you post the jvm application deployment on k8s? Or `kubectl describe deployment <jvm_deployment_name>`?

Comment: @Crou is there a particular part you're interested in? Unfortunately, I can't share the full deployment description, but I see that almost all the params are application-specific and don't mention neither ports nor network nor anything along these lines

Comment: Are ports 1098 and 10900 mentioned in the deployment? Have you exposed those ports via a service?

Comment: @Crou nope, no ports are mentioned there. No 1099 either

Comment: Then how does 1099 port-forward work? This is odd.

Comment: @Crou I added an upd to the post. Thank you for trying to help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full JMX URL for connecting to `localhost` is as follows:

```
service:jmx:rmi://localhost:<port1>/jndi/rmi://localhost:<port2>/jmxrmi
```

...[where](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html) `<port1>` is the port number on which the RMIServer and RMIConnection remote objects are exported and `<port2>` is the port number of the RMI Registry.

For port `1098` you could try

```
service:jmx:rmi://localhost:1098/jndi/rmi://localhost:1098/jmxrmi
```

I'd guess that both ports default to `1099` if not explicitly configured.

---

EDIT: Per the comments, the JMX URL that worked was:

```
service:jmx:rmi://localhost:1098/jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
```

Comment: Almost! This one works: `service:jmx:rmi://localhost:1098/jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi` (the second one is 1099). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad that it did :-) I'll edit the answer to include the JMX URL that worked for you.